# What else can cause an AxWindowsMediaPlayer to play?

Tags: vb.net, timer, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a button in my program that grabs a bunch of information from a `DataGridView` object (volume, url, delay, etc) and using that, it plays a file. I'm trying to get the delay to work (wait x number of seconds before playing) and I'm pretty it will work, but whenever I press the button, the play starts immediately. There is no `Ctlcontrols.play()` anywhere in the program except after the delay, so I have no idea what is causing it to play.

I explained my problem a little bit more in comments. Sorry if I didn't explain my code very well. If you could just tell my what else could be causing my player to start immediately, that would probably be enough.

```
'snd_btn_go is the button that is supposed to start it.
'This sub doesn't matter as much for the problem, it will just go to SndCueGO() if both numbers are in the valid range.
Private Sub snd_btn_go_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles snd_btn_go.Click
    Dim cue1 As Integer
    Dim cue2 As Integer
    cue1 = If(Integer.TryParse(snd_txt_cue_1.Text, cue1), Int(snd_txt_cue_1.Text), snd_num1)

    If snd_txt_cue_2.Text <> "" Then
        cue2 = If(Integer.TryParse(snd_txt_cue_2.Text, cue2), Int(snd_txt_cue_2.Text), snd_num2)
    Else
        cue2 = -1
    End If
    If (cue1 <= dgSound.Rows.Count - 1 And cue1 > 0) Then 
        SndCueGO(cue1, cue2)
    End If
End Sub

'This sub pulls all the info from the correct row in the DataGrid and assigns it to a list. It'll check if the start volume and end volume are the same and if they're not, it'll fade to the end volume.
Private Sub SndCueGO(cue1, cue2)

    Dim cues() = {cue1, cue2}
    snd_num1 = cue1

    Dim cuedata1 = snd_ds.Tables(0).Rows(cue1 - 1)
    Dim cuedata2 = snd_ds.Tables(0).Rows(cue1 - 1)

    If cue2 <> -1 Then
        snd_num2 = cue2
        cuedata2 = snd_ds.Tables(0).Rows(cue2 - 1)
    End If

    Dim data() = {cuedata1, cuedata2}

    For i = 0 To 1
        If cues(i) <> -1 Then
            snd_delay(i) = data(i).Item("Delay")
            snd_startvol(i) = safeNum(data(i).Item("Start_Vol."))
            snd_file(i) = data(i).Item("File")
            snd_in(i) = data(i).Item("Fade_In")
            snd_out(i) = data(i).Item("Fade_Out")
            snd_vol(i) = safeNum(data(i).Item("Vol."))
            snd_hold(i) = data(i).Item("Hold")
            snd_af(i) = If(data(i).Item("AF") = "", False, True)
            player_list(i).URL = snd_file(i)

            snd_current(i) = snd_startvol(i)

            If snd_startvol(i) <> snd_vol(i) Then 'snd_startvol(i) and snd_vol(i) were the same in all my tests, so this should not run.
                snd_next(i) = snd_vol(i)

                Dim num_steps_up = snd_in(i) * snd_speed
                Dim num_steps_down = snd_out(i) * snd_speed
                Dim diff = snd_vol(i) - snd_startvol(i)
                Dim small_step As Single
                If diff > 0 Then
                    small_step = diff / num_steps_up
                ElseIf diff < 0 Then
                    small_step = diff / num_steps_down
                End If
                snd_steps(i) = small_step

                timer_snd_fade.Tag = 0
                timer_snd_fade.Enabled = True

            End If

            timer_snd_master.Tag = 0 'resets the tag to 0
            timer_snd_master.Enabled = True 'Starts timer

        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub timer_snd_master_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer_snd_master.Tick
    If sender.Tag = snd_delay(0) Then
        Player1.Ctlcontrols.play() 'This is the only play command in the program
        Debug.Print("tag " & sender.Tag) 'These print after the delay
        Debug.Print("delay " & snd_delay(0))
    End If

    sender.Tag += 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the:

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer player1 = ...; // get the player from UI
IWMPSettings sett = player.settings;

sett.autoStart == ??
```

see [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564325(v=vs.85).aspx).

Probably it is set to `true`, as it's default value. Simply set it to false it the player will not play until `Ctlcontrols.play()` is invoked.